# Form not sending on website

Tags: php, forms

I have a form not sending on my website - nothing happens when you click the submit button. (ie the email is not sent and I am not seeing any error messages.)

I have double checked and the action from the form is going to the correct place - aka the contactsubmit.php file is being linked.

I'm sure that I am probably doing something stupid but after going through this a few times I can't find it.

**Form code:**

```
<form method="post" id="contact-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="contactsubmit.php">                          
  <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Your Name">
  <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Your Email">
  <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" value="" placeholder="Phone Number">
  <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" class="pull-right" name="submit" value="Send Message">
</form>
```

**PHP Code:** (contactsubmit.php)

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
$today = date("F j, Y, g:ia");
$ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$fullname=strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
$fullname=ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9 \s\'\-]", "", $fullname);
$fullname=ucwords($fullname);

$sendname=$fullname;

$email=strtolower($_REQUEST['email']);

$phone=$_POST["phone"];

$othermessage=strip_tags(trim($_POST["message"]));
$othermessage=ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9 \s.!\'\-\_\/.,]", "", $othermessage);
if(!empty($othermessage)) {$othermessage="Message: ".$othermessage;}
else {$othermessage="Message: NA";}

$to = "myemail@email.com";
$subject="Subject";
$from = "noreply@email.net";

$from_name = "From Name";
$name = $from_name;

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\n";

$headers .= 'From: My Website <noreply@email.com>' . "\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $fullname. ' <'.$email.'>' . "\n";

mail($to,$subject,$html_message,$headers);

echo "<p style=\"text-align: left;\"> MY Message Here</p>";
}

else {echo "ERROR";}
?>
```

**EDIT**

I am trying to help a friend out (aka I didn't originally write the site) so as you guys give suggestions I am learning a bit more about the site...

I found this in a js file:

```
jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({
    target: "#form-message",
    url: "contactsubmit.php",
    success: function() {
    $('#formdiv').fadeOut( "slow" );}
    });
}
```

There is a form message code in the contactsubmit.php page but I took it out because it was just the final message. Here is the code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#form-message').offset().top
}, 700);
</script>
```

Other useful information:

- The Hosting is through GoDaddy and is Windows Plesk
- It was working at some point ... I don't know if a file got deleted or changed.

Comment: email is not sending?

Comment: If "nothing happens" *at all* then it sounds like there's some client-side code somewhere intercepting the button click event or form submit event and canceling it.

Comment: Are you working on a localhost? Because the problem could be that the `mail()` funciton isn't working

Comment: does your form redirected to contactsubmit.php? if both files are at same position then remove / from form action

Comment: Instead of guessing what the issue might be I suggest you start debugging. 1. check your http servers access log file if the request comes in at all. 2. check the error log file if it comes in for a hint on what is broken. 3. if the request does _not_ come in to the server, then open your browsers development console, select the network tab and check what happens to the request on the client side.

Comment: I edited the post above but the email is not being sent and I am not getting any errors that I can see. It's like I never pushed the button.

Comment: it is possible if you are using a jquery a prevent default can stop submit button

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** OP Updated post - turns out it is jQuery submit...

1st replace `action="/contactsubmit.php">` with `action="contactsubmit.php">`

then do this in php file:

```
if(mail($to,$subject,$html_message,$headers))
echo "mail done";
else
echo "we got here";
```

This will check your `mail()` function which I assume is the problem

Comment: This is a very wild guess to what the problem _might_ be.

Comment: If we assume it is localhost it is not really a wild guess.... since there is no error displayed, I'm assuming it is the mail function.

Comment: Why are you convinced that a relative path is what the OP wants? No error shown may have a lot of causes. What makes you certain the mail() function is the issue? but most of all: _why not try to find out what the cause actually is before trying to explain what to change?_

Comment: It still didn't do anything when I did that in the php file. And I removed the / in the action

Comment: Are you running on localhost? If so can you check your logs?

Comment: I am not exactly sure there the logs are but am happy to check. I added more information to the post so hopefully that helps.

Comment: So you are using jQuery to submit the form... well then classic php submit is expected to not work :)

Comment: So then I don't need the action= part? It still is sending the form through the contactsubmit.php and it isn't working. Would this be a JS error rather then a php one?